# LINQ GroupBy child of a child

Tags: c#, linq

I am not sure if this question is a duplicate or not as this is something that I struggled a lot to search for as basically I don't know what would be the functionality name. So if that's the case my apologies.

Take an example where a team has persons and the person has several phone numbers, I would like to group by Number and still maintain all the information related with the team. So basically make the property Number the key of my groupby.

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
   public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
  public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
  public List<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Team> teams = new List<Team>();
```

So I would like to do something similar to:

`Team.Persons.GroupBy(i=> i.PhoneNumbers.Number)`

which obviously I can't because PhoneNumbers is a List

The end result should be something like

- Number1234 -> Team1, Team2
- Number5678 -> Team1, Team2, Team3

Where NumberX is the groupby key and TeamX contains the information associated with a team that has a member with that phone number.

It might be that my approach is entirely out of place on this example so any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically need to flatten the results so you've got team/number pairs and *then* you can group by the number. So for example:

```
// IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Team>>
var grouped = from team in teams
              from person in team.Persons
              from number in person.PhoneNumbers
              group team by number.Number;
```

You might also want to consider creating a `Lookup` instead of grouping:

```
// ILookup<string, Team>
var lookup = (from team in teams
              from person in team.Persons
              from number in person.PhoneNumbers
              select new { team, number }).ToLookup(p => p.number.Number,
                                                    p => p.team);
```

With the lookup, you can just do things like:

```
var number = "...";
foreach (var team in lookup[number])
{
    ...
}
```

... and it will helpfully return an empty sequence if you ask for the teams with an unknown phone number.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking! Thanks Jon. The Lookup seems to be way more close to what I want to use. One thing that I noticed it that the final line should probably be

Comment: select new { number, team }).ToLookup(p => p.number.Number,p => p.team);  aside from that spot on

Comment: @rjso: Why? It doesn't matter what order the properties in the anonymous type are here...

Comment: Yup you are right. Obviously didn't pay enough attention. My apologies

Answer (score 1):

One of approaches will be to select all phone numbers and their related teams and then you can do grouping like:

```
var teamsGrouppedByPhoneNumbers = (from t in Teams
from p in t.Persons
from pn in p.PhoneNumbers
select new { Team = t, PhoneNumber = pn })
.GroupBy(x => x.PhoneNumber.Number)
.ToList();
```